# Plotly marker legend appears multiple times on plot

Tags: r, plotly

I have a bar plot with bars colored according to a factor variable. I need to place a target marker on each bar at a designated location. I am able to place the marker on the plot without issue, but in the legend, the target marker appears three times, while I would only like it to appear once. I believe this behavior is linked to the coloring of the bars, but this coloring is something that must be retained. Can anybody provide me with a solution so that the target marker only appears on the legend only once?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data.frame(grp = c("x", "y", "z") %>% as.factor,
           vals = c(10, 15, 20)) %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~vals,
    y = ~grp,
    color = ~grp,
    colors = c("red", "green", "blue"),
    type = "bar"
  ) %>% 
  add_markers(name = "target",
              x = 17,
              marker = list(
                color = "black")
              )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments in `plot_ly` will be set for all traces as long as there are not overwritten. In your case `color = ~grp` inside the `plot_ly` function will group each trace by `grp`.

An easy option is to define the bars with its colors in an own trace.

**Code**

```
data.frame(grp = c("x", "y", "z") %>% as.factor,
           vals = c(10, 15, 20)) %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~vals,
    y = ~grp
  ) %>% 
  add_bars(color = ~grp,
           colors = c("red", "green", "blue")) %>%
  add_markers(name = "target",
              x = 17,
              marker = list(
                color = "black")
  )
```

In this code, x and y are shared by bars and markers but colors are defined separately in each trace. Therefore you get individual legends for bars and a single legend for markers.

**Plot**
[image]